# Laravel 5 environment detection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-environment

I'm trying to get environment detection to work, so that I can use the .env.local.php file and all the other goodies, but somehow I cannot get it to detect the right environment.

I have added bootstrap/environment.php

```
<?php

$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('mylocalmachinename') 

));
```

But when I php artisan env, I always get production instead of local.

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Are you sure, that the machine name is really the same? Does the case of letters match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment detection has changed in Laravel5.

You now put a `.env` file in the project root

```
APP_ENV=local
```

Then on another computer - you might do

```
APP_ENV=staging
```

You can then add additional environmental items - i.e.

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=homestead
```

Comment: Laravel 5 is still under development. Its not even in Beta yet at the time of this post. Once it is ready, the docs will be updated

Comment: Quick note about .env: This file is different for every environment and it is .gitignored by default. You should recreate it (or ftp it) in your production environment with the correct values!

Comment: @Laurence what is if else function to detect environment?